# Explain recurrence and Dynamic Programming methods

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, dynamic-programming

Well during competitive programming, Dynamic Programming and Recursion is one of the most favorite topics. It kind of draws the line between an average and a good coder. Now my question is, is there some pattern that is seen when you solve such questions? By this I mean, is there always some specific approach or direction that one should head to when tackling such problems. I see some people are pretty good at making recurrences and things are pretty obvious to them, while to others it's more of a nightmare. Is it just immense practice or have they understood the right idea behind such questions and always approach it in a specific way? Maybe someone could tell me what they feel when they approach such questions. Is there some article that kind of hit them and made things crystal clear in this domain.

I understand that this might be categorized as "Too broad for a question" but I was just hoping if someone could explain how they approach such problems, how do they understand the overlapping problems, how to think of the dp states and intricacies like these.

Comment: Have you read "Concrete mathematics"? https://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: @shimak, the feeling (the instincts) will develop with practice, where by practice I mean you read the theory and do problem solving. For a great intro to dynamic programming have a look at the chapter in https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition (I used it myself, this is an amazing book, cannot recommend enough). To get a good command of these ideas, you actually need to do it. There is no magic here, just try to solve a lot of problems ( yourself !!! ), then the feeling should come, and you should be able to spot the patterns.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this as well!